# URL and regex with django

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a problem with the urls.py in my django project

I have an url like this:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/cars/?page=2
then when i clik on next it will be :

http://127.0.0.1:8000/cars/cars?page=3

and I have en error :(

the url is :

url(r'^cars/$page=n', TaskViewSet.as_view()),

Comment: care to tell us what the error is?

Comment: this is the message error :

Comment: Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/cars/cars?page=3
Using the URLconf defined in TaskAPI.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^$
^cars/$
^admin/
The current URL, cars/cars, didn't match any of these.

Comment: Use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36912807/edit) button to add new information. Also include what you have tried/researched already to solve the problem.

Comment: show us your template file

Comment: {% if is_paginated %}
        <div class="pagination">
            <span class="page-links">
                {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                    <a href="cars?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
 {% endif %}
                <span class="page-current">
                    Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
                </span>
                {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                    <a href="cars?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
                {% endif %}
            </span>
        </div>
 endif...

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are linking next/previous pages like `<a href="cars?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">` in your template.

You should make following changes to your project:

Rename url conf, like @jonatron suggested:

```
url(r'^cars/$', TaskViewSet.as_view()),
```

Then in your templates, make sure you link next/previous pages with their absolute positions, like this:

```
<a href="/cars/?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
```

Also,  you can name your url conf and generate the full url without having to rewrite everytime:

```
url(r'^cars/$', TaskViewSet.as_view(), name='cars'),

<a href="{% url 'cars' %}?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need:

```
url(r'^cars/$', TaskViewSet.as_view()),
```

Anything after the ? is a query string, which does not get matched in the URL patterns. You can access the ?page value in the view, eg:

```
page = request.GET['page']
```

Comment: this is my view: from django.views.generic import ListView

class TaskViewSet(ListView):
 model = Task
 template_name = 'task.html'
 context_object_name = "car_list"
 paginate_by = 1
 page = request.GET['page'] but i have an error in request Unsolved reference, do I replace Listview by request? thank u